# Creating a graph by using adjacency matrix

Tags: c, function, matrix, graph, malloc

Here is my stucture

```
struct node{
    int V,E;
    int **adj;
};
```

Here is my code to create a graph:

```
struct node* create()
{
    int i,j,x,y;
    struct node *G=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Write the number of vertex and edges\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&G->V,&G->E);
    G->adj=malloc(sizeof(int)*(G->V * G->V));
    if(!G->adj){
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        return;
    }
    for(i=0;i<G->V;i++)
    for(j=0;j<G->V;j++)
    G->adj[i][j]=0;
    printf("\nWrite the source node and destination: ");
    for(i=0;i<G->E;i++){
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    G->adj[x][y]=1;
    G->adj[y][x]=1;
    }
    return(G);
}
```

and I am storing the pointer returned by this function in another pointer like this:

```
int main()
{
    struct node *G=create();
}
```

When I compile the program, I'm asked for the number of vertex and edges but as soon as I enter the values, my program crashes. I want to know the reason. Is this because of memory allocation failure?

Comment: What I see are small nits.  No checks for valid inputs (vertex count, edge count, node numbers when entering graph edges), no check for G being NULL, and no value on return statement when malloc returns NULL.  That last bit won't even compile on the compilers I use.

Comment: Two notes about your adjacency matrix: First, calloc() will zero the matrix for you, and if your matrix is going to be all 0 and 1 values you can save memory by using `char` instead of `int` for the element type.

But first, you might want to say what input you were using...

Comment: @MikeHousky That's okay! But I can't have any memory problem. I have a 4 GB RAM. Something is wrong with my code. Can you guess what's wrong?

Comment: "But first, you might want to say what input you were using."  I get no errors on the compile, after the return statement fix.

Comment: I was using 4 for the number of vertices and 5 for the number of edges. For the adjacency matrix, I'll be using 0 and 1

Comment: Never mind...I found it.  You are implementing a matrix as an array of row pointers in the struct, but allocating it as a flat 1-D array.  I'll compose an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C99 style variable length arrays are only useful with local variables or arguments. So, you have the two classic C methods available to implement a 2D array.

1. Array of pointers:

That's what your struct looks like.  With that, you need separate allocations for the pointer array and data:

```
G->adj = calloc(G->V, sizeof (int*));
assert(G->adj != NULL); /* need assert.h for this */
for (i=0; i<G-V; ++i)
{
    G->adj[i] = calloc(G->V, sizeof (int));
    assert(G->adj[i] != NULL);
}
```

It's a bit easier on memory to do one bulk allocation of the array data and then use pointer arithmetic to set the `G->adj[]` pointers, but the above gives the idea that, as far as C is concerned, each row is a separate array.

2. Just one bulk array, with explicit cell location calculation done on each access.  This is what C does internally with nested arrays.

Change the type of `adj` to just `int*` and then:

```
G->adj = calloc(G->V * G->V, sizeof (int));
assert(G->adj != NULL);
```

That's it.  Now when you access an element, use `G->adj[i*G->V + j]`, instead of `G->adj[i][j]`.  Macros may help with readability.

Comment: Of course there are variable-length 2d arrays, though you're correct in that such cannot be stored into a global structure. However, your use of `assert`  is not correct, as `assert` is used to state the invariants i.e. things that can never happen in correct code but `calloc` can return `NULL` memory is exhausted, even if the program is correct.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Can both dimensions vary in a 2D VLA?  (I don't use them 'cause I need things to compile on--ugh--Visual C++.)  Anyway, the assert is just there to halt the test run during debugging if there is any failure.  Assertion failures are a lousy UI for production, even if there were no semantic objections.

Comment: Yes, both dimensions can vary. But indeed the limited scope of variably-modified types means it is not the answer here.